# Express returning undefined value when reading from mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am creating a basic login page in ReactJS with Node /Express and mysql and when I get a value from my database, the program says its undefined but I have no idea how to fix this. I am very new to React and Node so not sure why this doesnt work.

This are the libraries im importing:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dbConnection = require('./dbConfig');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
```

This is my code:

```
app.get("/checkPassword", async(req,res)=>{
    const {name, email, passwordl} = req.body;
    const query = "SELECT password FROM account WHERE `name` = ? AND `email` = ?";
    dbConnection.query(query,[name,email], async(err,data)=>{
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        return await bcrypt.compare(passwordl, data[0].password);
    })
})
```

This is the error im getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')
```

Comment: That means the query didn't select any rows -- there's no user with the given name and email. You need to check `data.length` to tell if the query matched anything.

Comment: It's not an error for the `WHERE` conditions not to match anything, so `if (err)` doesn't handle this situation.

Comment: So, aside from your main issue,  `return await bcrypt.compare(passwordl, data[0].password);` isn't going to accomplish anything here.  You're just returning a promise to an async callback which does nothing useful at all.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and see what you're getting back from the database.

Comment: @jfriend00 i dont understand why im not getting any data back from the database. I have another query where i use req.params.name from the URL and that returns data fine

Comment: Well, your code fails because you don't check the results of the query to see if you go a result.  The query fails because what you're putting into the query doesn't match anything in the database.  This just requires very basic debugging where you look at all the input parameters and look at the resulting query you build and then see why it's not matching something in the database.  There's nothing we can do here.  You have to do BASIC debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I see you are having a problem requesting the code for mysql, this is probably because when you do the Query for the database it even does the search but returns nothing because it didn't find the parameters you used. Try checking when users make the request, example:

```
if (data.length === 0) {
    return res.json({ success: false, message: "Usuário não encontrado." });
}
```

If this doesn't work, try configuring the Body Parser to capture the data from front to back, and it's also always a good idea to check if MySQL is returning something if I haven't been, check the query.